# Can we use interrupt 5,6,7 in microprocessor 8085 instead of 5.5,6.5 and 7.5?

Tags: microprocessors, 8085

In microprocessor 8085 we use 5 interrupts in which 7.5,6.5 and 5.5 are three of them.
Can we use interrupt 5,6,7 in microprocessor 8085 instead of 5.5,6.5 and 7.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO.It is not possible.

As you might know 5.5,6.5 and 7.5 are hardware interrupts and 5,6 and 7 are software interrupts. Hardware interrupts can be triggered or initiated by external devices by providing appropriate signals to the pins But in case of software interrupts it is to be included in the program and when it is executed that interrupt will be triggered. They also differ in several other reasons too.For more reference you can visit [here](http://www.idc-online.com/control1/Interrupts_of_intel_8085.pdf) .

Thus they both aren't same and you cannot replace one kind with another type.